# Is it possible to define a letterhead header in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

R gurus,

I am struggling to design a letterhead template in Rmarkdown for a massive mail merge project.

What I ideally need is something like following:
[image]

Question is if the header can be defined in YAML? The code might look something like following:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: false

logo: logo.png
institute: UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA
name: Prof. Jones
address: Mathematics Search Committee
         Department of Mathematics
         University of California
         Berkeley, California 12345
email: pj@uc.ac

latex_engine: pdflatex
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
# spacing: double
endnote: no
---
```

Comment: Have you seen the [pandoc-letter template](https://github.com/aaronwolen/pandoc-letter)? It might be just what you need.

Comment: I would just copy the default template ( https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex ) and edit the head according to what you need. Afterwards include the tempalte by using the YAML option `template`.

Comment: What is the dynamic part of the document?

Comment: Dynamic part would be a personalised letter written in Markdown with details like exam scores etc.

Comment: I know of two letter-oriented packages on CRAN: `linl` and `komaletter`. Neither of them seems to fit the bill completely, but both might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

```
---
title: "Prof. Jones  \nDepartment  \nUniversity  \nState  \nEmail"
output: pdf_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \usepackage{graphicx} 
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushright}\LARGE\includegraphics[width=8cm]{logo.jpg}\\[\bigskipamount]}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushright}}
---
```

[image]

Add your logo to where it has `{logo.jpg}` and the width might need altering as well.

Bit of a workaround using double space and `\n` to add a line break to the heading to create the address.

`flushright` right aligns the logo and title then.